# iframe location is null

Tags: javascript, iframe, location

Sometimes I use:

```
window.frames[framename].location.href
```

..only to find firebug reporting `window.frames[framename].location` is null, why would this be?

Comment: makes you wonder when the poster can't be bothered fixing spelling mistakes in the title...

Answer (score 1):

Is the frame in another domain?  you might find yourself being restricted because you can't access content from another domain (e.g. XSS)